# Add datetime in pandas dataframe to existing row based on column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to pandas and am having a problem with this. I have a simple table:

```
         date  period_number
0  2016-10-26              1
1  2016-10-26              3
2  2016-10-26              5
3  2016-10-27              1
```

I want to create 3 equal sized period with start and end times, like this:

```
         date  period_number               start                end                                   
0  2016-10-26              1    2016-10-26 00:00   2016-10-26 08:00  
1  2016-10-26              3    2016-10-26 08:00   2016-10-26 16:00    
2  2016-10-26              5    2016-10-26 16:00   2016-10-27 00:00                    
3  2016-10-27              1    2016-10-27 00:00   2016-10-27 08:00
```

I tried to do something like this:

```
for (period, group) in df.groupby('period'):
    if period == 1:
        group['start'] = group['date']
        group['end'] = group['date'] + timedelta(hours=8)
    if period == 3:
        group['start'] = group['date'] + timedelta(hours=8)
        group['end'] = group['date'] + timedelta(hours=16)
    if period == 5:
        group['start'] = group['date'] + timedelta(hours=16)
        group['end'] = group['date'] + timedelta(days=1)
```

But I'm getting errors:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Also tried this but obviously wrong and getting same error:

```
df[df['period'] == 1]['end'] = df['date'] + timedelta(hours=8)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach is to use an apply that looks at the period integer and uses that to add a variable number of hours to the date. It's a bit hacky but does the trick.
It would be cleaner if the period numbers would be simply 1 2 3.

```
# Initialise dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([['2016-10-26', '2016-10-26', '2016-10-26', '2016-10-27'], [1, 3, 5, 1]]).T
df.columns = ['date', 'period_number']
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(pd.to_datetime)

# Make start column
df['start'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.date + timedelta(hours=8 * (x.period_number - 1) / 2), 1)

# End column is just start column + 8 hours
df['end'] = df.start + timedelta(hours=8)
```

This returns:

```
date    period_number   start   end
0   2016-10-26  1   2016-10-26 00:00:00 2016-10-26 08:00:00
1   2016-10-26  3   2016-10-26 08:00:00 2016-10-26 16:00:00
2   2016-10-26  5   2016-10-26 16:00:00 2016-10-27 00:00:00
3   2016-10-27  1   2016-10-27 00:00:00 2016-10-27 08:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks, I also realised that the data is always in order so I could actually just create a date_range with freq='8H' and add it to dataframe

Comment: That makes things easier ;)